# TightVNC Java Viewer connection

Tags: java, vnc, remote-server, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I have source code of the tight VNC and installed 'Real VNC' on my local system. When I run the source of tight VNC, it asked for the host and port so I passed following credentials: Host: 127.0.0.1 Port: 5800. Then I can see the status as connected on the console of my eclipse. But I am not able to see my local screen. Can anyone help me that how can I record my local screen using tight VNC?

I am getting EOF exception.

Comment: I am using windows 7 operating system and running my code using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Port: 5800 is a port that is mostly used by webSocket connections.
Try connecting through standart VNC port 5900.